# Passing password to Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, postgresql, process, runtime.exec, postgresql-8.4

I am trying to implement a feature to restart PostgreSQL server from Java code using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method. The method is working fine if the PostgreSQL server is not SSL enabled but if the PostgreSQL server is SSL enabled and if the private key is encrypted with a password, it requires passphrase to be passed. I tried with below code for implementing the same,

```
    String postgreSQLRestartCMD = 
      "/u/postgreSQL/pg_ctl -D /u/postgreSQL/data restart -w";  
         //-w option waits until the passphase is sent
    final Process restartPosgreSQLServer = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(postgreSQLRestartCMD);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(restartPosgreSQLServer.getOutputStream());
    ps.println("keyPassword"); // sending passphasse here
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
               public void run() {
               try {
                    IOUtils.copy(restartPosgreSQLServer.getInputStream(), logWriter);
                   }
               catch (final IOException e) {
                     logWriter.println("Error occurred while reading InputStream.");
                     e.printStackTrace(logWriter);
                   }
            }
     }).start();
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
               public void run() {
               try {
                    IOUtils.copy(restartPosgreSQLServer.getErrorStream(), logWriter);
                   }
                   catch (final IOException e) {
                      logWriter.println("Error occurred while reading ErrorStream.");
                      e.printStackTrace(logWriter);
                    }
                }
       }).start();
       int returnStatus = restartPosgreSQLServer.waitFor();
       if (returnStatus == 1) {
             logWriter.println("Error has occured while running PostgreSQL server.");
       } else {
              logWriter.println("PostgreSQL has started successfully.");
       }
```

But the server is not getting started. I am trying in Linux. In console it's getting stuck with below line and I guess passphrase not sent properly.

```
     Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

Where is this going wrong and why is the passphrase not sent?

### Edit

Upon digging further I just found that Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) is creating new process, my ps.println("password") is passed to parent process. But I am not sure whether my observation is right.

Answer (score 2):

What you are not taking into account is that before programs ask for the password, they **flush the input buffer**. Otherwise it would be very easy to have extra characters read in for password, that the user accidentally typed before the password prompt.

You'll have to raise the level of complexity of your code to analyze the process's output and print to its `stdin` only after actually witnessing the password prompt.